# Zend and .htaccess

Tags: apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

My default 'zend' app has this default structure

```
/zend + webroot
    /application
    /config
    /library
    /public
        .htaccess
        index.php
```

and the default .htaccess redirects the various controller/action details via ./public/index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I use this default url to access the app

```
http://domain/index.php
```

I've now moved to a shared host, where the webroot is above the 'zend' root.

```
/webroot
    /zend
        /application
        /config
        /public
            index.php
           .htaccess
```

but i can only access my app via this URL

```
http://domain/zend/public/index.php
```

i want to be able to use

```
http://domain/zend/index.php
```

and have .htaccess redirect.

and i'm wondering how i can tweak the .htaccess file to redirect the URL requests. I read
this [tutorial](http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html) but i didn;t work for me

```
/webroot
    /zend
        .htaccess
        /application
        /config
        /library
        /public
            index.php
```

This is the .htaccess content in this case

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Can anybody spot anything?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create  zend/index.php containing this code:

```
<?php include 'public/index.php';
```

Now create zend/.htaccess containing this code:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Make sure that your images/css/js files are all within zend/public/ and do not remove the zend/public/.htaccess file :)

Don't forget that the request's baseUrl doesn't include '/public', so you'll need to add it yourself when you reference public facing files.

Regards,

Rob...

Comment: i tried out your method - however the webpage lost all formatting (access to css etc). I'm using the skeleton application

Comment: the tutorial on the link provided by emeraldjava actually worked for me. is there something incorrect in it that one shouldn't be doing?

Comment: @Rob Allen it is work for me. one quetion, how to set basePath globally so it can get public facing file? Thanks.

Comment: ok, got it place this in view_manager array `'base_path' => '/zend2/public/',` in `module.config.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to change your [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase).

Answer (score 0):

Most shared hosts I've used still allow you to upload files outside the web root.  For example,

```
/home/{username}/webroot/
```

...you can still upload to `/home/{username}/` like:

```
/webroot
    index.php
   .htaccess
/application
/config
```

Then in your bootstrap, just replace `public` with `webroot`, or if you have ssh access delete the existing webroot and replace it with a symbolic link to the zend public directory, like:

```
rm -f webroot
ln -s public webroot
```