# Zend redirect problem

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to redirect to

```
http://localhost/site/public/admin/login
```

from

```
http://localhost/site/public
```

but for some reason, it keeps redirecting to

```
http://localhost/admin/login
```

The code I am using is:

```
$this->_response->setRedirect('/admin/login')->sendResponse();
```

This is really frustrating me, and any help would be grealy appreciated

Answer (score 2):

try this  :

> > $this->_response->setRedirect('admin/login')->sendResponse();

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble upon this problem. this might help. actually encountered this same problem and found this and it worked for me.Cheers

- [Zend and .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003101/zend-and-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is within a controller context.

If so, use the *Redirector* helper

```
return $this->_helper->redirector('login', 'admin');
```