# Zend and assets location

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

Here is the structure of my Zend project

```
project
  application
    .....
    modules
      admin
    .....
  models
  views
  public
    assets
      images
        frontend
           layout.css
```

The problem is that when I try to reach http://cms.com/assets/images/frontend/some_image.gif I get

```
Invalid controller specified (assets)
```

I guess the problem can be solved by using htaccess but I dont know how.

Comment: What does your htaccess currently contain?

Comment: Just one line - SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

Comment: You're missing the default htaccess that's included with ZF. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003101/zend-and-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You need add (for example):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js)$
```

See your htaccess file