# How to set the rewrite condition for a Zend Framework 1.12 project on production server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I read a lot of guides about how to deploy a Zend Framework 1.12 project to a production environment, and I think I did all the steps, but I can't configure the re write rules on the .htaccess, First to know, the server is a shared one, so, I cant access to any configuration, so, the problem is only the redirection to my /public/inedx.php file.

First at all, in my main folder ( / ) I added a .htaccess file with this content based on the official guide `(http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.rewrite.html  -> Rewriting inside a VirtualHost )`:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I uploaded this file to my main ( / ) and the 404 error is still displayed.

then, I added a index.php in my main ( / ) whit this:

```
<?php 
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

And now my web is working but not completely, i mean, there is no css styles, no js, and no image, but only if I use the $this->baseUrl(), so, when in my layout I use a css link like this:

```
> <link href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()."/css/global.css"; ?>"
> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

a 404 appear:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.mysite.com/css/global.css"
```

When it should be http://www.mysite.com/public/css/global.css, so, I edit my layout and the js and css are now working, but when I click on a link, like:

http://www.mysite.com/controller/action/#0-0

I get another 404....

so, someone have experience on this? dealing against the devil?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is you index.php file in the /public/ folder ?

Comment: throw some garbage text into your .htaccess file just to see if the webserver is parsing it at all. Expected behavior would be a 500 error

Comment: Hi joellrod, the default index.php is inside the /public/ folder with the default code.

Comment: Hi Orangepill, I edited my /public/.htaccess and I got a 505 error when I enter to mysite.com/public, what that means?

Comment: still not working, I can see only my layout with my index content (only the view, I didn't generate a controller for index), some Ideas? some manual to read?

Answer (score 0):

Do not

```
include 'public/index.php';
```

Best way of dealing with this is to move the public/index.php along with the .htaccess into the root folder. Once done amend APPLICATION_PATH in the index.php from

```
/../application
```

to

```
application
```

I am not sure what

```
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
```

is supposed to be doing either.

Answer (score -1):

you can try below url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

[Zend and .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003101/zend-and-htaccess)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Link-only answers aren't too welcome on this website. You should try explaining the code!

Comment: Well thanks, i thought link might help more, so just provided link will see to it next time.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't put the link - on the contrary! But try to give it a bit of context :)